# Error installing dnvm on windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd, dnvm

I am trying to do a fresh install of dnvm using the command

```
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
```

through powershell, but I keep getting this frustrating error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Everywhere I look online says to use that command, and I have not found a fix for my problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: dnvm is dead. Check out http://dot.net

Comment: Right now can I use that instead of dnvm to run commands like dnu publish but like a new form of it? If I upgrade my project will it help? How can I do that without messing it up? Telling me to use the new version of something isn't really a solution to my problem.

Comment: Is it possible you are on an older version of Powershell? The command you posted worked fine for me on PS 5.0.10586.122.

Comment: I checked and I am on version 5. Don't remember the minor value but its definitely not an outdated version. It's truly mind boggling that it doesn't work. Installing visual studio gave me the dnvm command that I wanted, but I have not been able to do this command yet.